# CM10.1, GS II, Mount command for encrypted sdcard0

Tags: cyanogenmod, encryption, internal-sd

**Question**: What is the syntax for the mount command within android to mount an encrypted file system?

**Context**:
I'm using CM10.1 (currently cm-10.1-20130604-NIGHTLY-I9100) on a Samsung Galaxy S2 (i9100) and have encrypted my internal sdcard.  On AndrOId 4.2 the internal sdcard (which is not a physical sdcard, rather a partition of the devices memory) is /storage/sdcard0, it has a link that points to /sdcard

After encrypting and rebooting the 3rd or 4th time sdcard0 doesn't mount.  Further reboots don't fix the problem.

/storage/sdcard1 (the physically removable sdcard) mounts fine.

When sdcard0 was mounted properly the output of the "mount" command included the following line which is now missing.

`tmpfs on /storage/sdcard0 type tmpfs (rw,relatime,mode=050,gid=1028)`

So,

1. What is the proper format of the mount command to remount this drive?
2. Any suggestions on how to fix or trouble shoot this problem?

Thanks

Ed

Edit: posting relevant section of logcat

```
Volume sdcard0 state changing -1 (Initializing) -> 0 (No-Media)
Volume sdcard0 state changing 0 (No-Media) -> 2 (Pending)
Volume sdcard0 state changing 2 (Pending) -> 1 (Idle-Unmounted)
got storage path: /storage/sdcard0 description: Internal storage primary: true removable: false emulated: false mtpReserve: 0 allowMassStorage: true maxFileSize: 0
addVolumeLocked() StorageVolume [mStorageId=0 mPath=/storage/sdcard0 mDescriptionId=17040710 mPrimary=true mRemovable=false mEmulated=false mMtpReserveSpace=0 mAllowMassStorage=true mMaxFileSize=0 mOwner=null]
volume state changed for /storage/sdcard0 (null -> unmounted)
got storage path: /storage/sdcard0 description: Internal storage primary: true removable: false emulated: false mtpReserve: 0 allowMassStorage: true maxFileSize: 0
addVolumeLocked() StorageVolume [mStorageId=0 mPath=/storage/sdcard0 mDescriptionId=17040710 mPrimary=true mRemovable=false mEmulated=false mMtpReserveSpace=0 mAllowMassStorage=true mMaxFileSize=0 mOwner=null]
volume state changed for /storage/sdcard0 (null -> unmounted)
/dev/block/vold/259:10 being considered for volume sdcard0
Volume sdcard0 state changing 1 (Idle-Unmounted) -> 3 (Checking)
Volume sdcard0 state changing 3 (Checking) -> 1 (Idle-Unmounted)
volume state changed for /storage/sdcard0 (unmounted -> checking)
sendStorageIntent Intent { act=android.intent.action.MEDIA_CHECKING dat=file:///storage/sdcard0 (has extras) } to UserHandle{-1}
volume state changed for /storage/sdcard0 (checking -> unmounted)
sendStorageIntent Intent { act=android.intent.action.MEDIA_UNMOUNTED dat=file:///storage/sdcard0 (has extras) } to UserHandle{-1}
volume state changed for /storage/sdcard0 (unmounted -> nofs)
sendStorageIntent Intent { act=android.intent.action.MEDIA_NOFS dat=file:///storage/sdcard0 (has extras) } to UserHandle{-1}
action: android.intent.action.MEDIA_UNMOUNTED path: /storage/sdcard0
Error opening directory '/storage/sdcard0/log/', skipping: Permission denied.
Permission Denial: broadcasting Intent { act=android.intent.action.MEDIA_MOUNTED dat=file:///storage/sdcard0 flg=0x10 } from berserker.android.apps.sshdroid (pid=5818, uid=10083) is not exported from uid 10017 due to receiver com.android.providers.downloads/.DownloadReceiver
action: android.intent.action.MEDIA_MOUNTED path: /storage/sdcard0
storage path "/storage/sdcard0" mounted readOnly=true
Error opening directory '/storage/sdcard0/log/', skipping: Permission denied.
```

Comment: A hint would be to take a look at the log files. You can do so either via ADB, or use a terminal app. Points of interest are `logcat` and `dmesg`. Search them for "sdcard0" to see whether an error shows up. Then either update your question with the details found or, if applyable, already add the solution as answer :)